# VS2012 is trying to access a network location that no longer exists when saving

Tags: visual-studio

I'm having an issue where Visual Studio 2012 hangs for way longer than it should whenever I do a manual save.  Previously it seemed to do this randomly, but I noticed that it was whenever it was doing an automatic save to the backup recovery files.  I have since disabled the AutoRecover system.

By using sysinternals Process Monitor, I learned that VS2012 is trying to access a network location that no longer exists, and not just when trying to save, but when starting up, etc.  Any time it is trying to access the `.../My Documents/Visual Studio 2012/` directory, it's looking in the wrong place:

[image]

What happened I believe is that when I originally installed 2012, \govstor-01 was the name of one of our servers.  I went back to using VS2010 for a while, and during that time our IT/Network guys renamed that server (simply removed the -01).

My question is:  Where is VS2012 saving that path and how do I change it?  It doesn't seem to be a system related thing because VS2010 and VS2013 RC both work perfectly fine so I'm not sure why 2012 is stuck with outdated 'hooks'.  Like I said, I disabled the AutoRecovery feature but it still seems to be trying to access that directory when doing a manual save.

Quick Edit:  I should note that I have tried reinstalling VS2012, as well as performing the 'Reset all settings' in the Import and Export Settings Wizard.

Comment: Run Regedit.exe and search for the server name.

Comment: Is this happening on an TFS linked project?

Comment: Yes, it's a TFS linked project, however the issue comes up when just loading visual studio.  I have no issue when opening the same project in VS2010 or 2013 RC.

Comment: I went with what @HansPassant suggested and just searched through the registry for that server name.  It was still listed in several entries under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>VisualStudio>11.0`.  I changed those to reflect the current server name and everything is working great now.
I'll give Hans a chance to add that as an answer if he wants, if not I'll answer it here in a day or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, there are several settings in Visual Studio that can refer to the original Documents directory.  Short from hunting through the Tools + Options settings, the easiest way to find them back is by searching the registry with Regedit.exe for the old server name.  And editing the value you find to now refer to the new server name.  Restart VS and you should be back in business.